# htaccess - how deny access to all resource expect for that resource called from hostname and gived file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have this .htaccess:

```
# Rewrite URL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^www.mydomain.com" [NC]
  RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/myfile.html" [NC]
  RewriteRule \.*$ - [F,NC]

</IfModule>
```

I want **DENY** access to **ALL** resources, **EXCEPT** for:

1. all resource from `HTTP_HOST` (es. [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com));
2. specific gived file (es. myfile.html).

The code above not work. As i can solve it?
Thanks

PS: In other words, i want to do something like:

```
<?php

    if ( 
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] !== "www.mydomain.com" ||
        $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] !== "/myfile.html"
    ) {
        // redirect 403
    } 
} 

?>
```

Comment: it domain of site. Own domain.

Comment: No, website is accessible using: www.mydomain.com. Just need deny all call to resource (from users) for example: /file.pdf but need allow which /file.pdf is accessible clicking from internal page. Same for xml file or css/audio/video file etc. Need be accessible from internal page but not from user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments I believe you need to check for referrer. You may try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}/*'"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/myfile\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule \. - [F]
```

Just keep in mind that `HTTP_REFERER` based blocking is not very strong protection as clients can spoof this header.

**Testing `curl` commands:**

```sh
curl --referer 'http://example.com/' -IL 'http://yourdomain.com/'

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Thu, 08 Apr 2021 09:28:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1j PHP/8.0.3
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

curl --referer 'http://yourdomain.com/' -IL 'http://yourdomain.com/'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 08 Apr 2021 09:27:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1j PHP/8.0.3
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**References:**

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)
- [.htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Comment: I have tried in local but so it continue to open .css file  if i type it directly from url. 
Just i want deny access to all files typed from url except when called from internal page. 
(I use css file as example of course, but in general i mean any internal files).

Comment: I know, for this i wanted use HTTP_HOST or REMOTE_HOST for get correctly hostname.

Comment: Done. So not open .css file from url but TOO not open .css file from internal page. I need allow access .css file from internal page.

Comment: I have tried to explain better adding to post too a example in php about what i want try to have. Maybe it help more to understand better what i want to do.

Comment: Ok. Working on HTTP_REFERER i saw which if resource  is called from internal page it contain value "www.mydomain.com" and when called from user it not contain it. I thinked to work on this.

Comment: Just tried your update. It load .css file in both cases.

Comment: Maybe i solved so:   RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}/*'" [NC] looking from apache org guide. But not sure yet. Can test too you?

Comment: This code works perfectly fine on my local apache. It blocks when URL is invoked directly in a browser. When I click from one page to another then there is no blocking. Test it independently without other rules and check value of  `HTTP_REFERER` every time. I dump all headers using `print_r(getallheaders());` function in a `test.php` file I have created.

Comment: To test use this curl command: `curl --referer 'http://example.com/' -IL 'http://yourdomain.com/'` and `curl --referer 'http://yourdomain.com/' -IL 'http://yourdomain.com/'`

Comment: how i mark the comment? can you update your post with the code take from apache.org ? or just tell me more (first time which me in this situation)